# How to read and reset spring actuator metrics?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using `spring-boot.1.3.0`, which provides ability to store custom `metrics` in memory as follows:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    private CounterService counterService;
    private GaugeService gaucheService;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(CounterService counterService) {
        this.counterService = counterService;
    }

    public void exampleMethod() {
        this.counterService.increment("services.system.myservice.invoked");
    }
}
```

Question: how can I read the counted values from the `CounterService` and `GaugeService` programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Autowired
private BufferMetricReader metrics;

int count = metrics.findOne("my.metrics.key").getValue().intValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

The Javadoc shows a `reset` method: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.3.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/CounterService.html

Reading has to be done from an exporter: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.3.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/export/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

@membersound's answer works, but I think it's better use

```
@Autowired
private MetricReader metricReader;
```

instead of

```
@Autowired
private BufferMetricReader metrics;
```